# Getting JS syntax errors on online ide but not on vsc or node

Tags: javascript, class, ide

I've got the following code

```
class Test {
  name = 'David';
  static var1 = 'John';
  printName() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  static staticMethod() {
    console.log('This is a static method');
  }
}
const test = new Test();
test.printName();
Test.staticMethod();
console.log(Test.var1);
```

It works fine on VSC with live server and also when running it on node, but I get syntax errors when running it on online IDEs such as jsfiddle or programiz.  I was wondering if anybody knows why that is?

Comment: ERROR: Unexpected token: name «Test», expected: punc «;»[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulSXh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a known bug in jsfiddle.  I guess other online ides must use the same parsing library.

https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1744

Comment: That's not only in jsfiddle, I didn't really give it time to check how it really works in the background, but it might be the way they parse and execute code to prevent stuff. worth giving it a look in the future